# How to configure slrn so that nano is the text editor?

Tags: command-line, configuration, text-editor, nano

How is slrn configured so that nano is used as an editor?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ grep vim .slrnrc 
%set editor_command "vim -c %d '%s'"
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ grep nano .slrnrc
%set editor_command "nano -c %d '%s'"
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ slrn --version
slrn 1.0.3
S-Lang Library Version: 2.3.3
    * Note: This program was compiled against version 2.3.2.
Operating System: Linux

COMPILE TIME OPTIONS:
 Backends: +nntp +slrnpull +spool
 External programs / libs: +canlock +inews +ssl +uudeview +iconv
 Features: +decoding +emphasized_text +end_of_thread +fake_refs +gen_msgid
    -grouplens -msgid_cache +piping +rnlock +spoilers -strict_from
 Using 64 bit integers for article numbers.

DEFAULTS:
 Default server object:     nntp
 Default posting mechanism: nntp
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release 
No LSB modules are available.
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

The documentation isn't overly specific on this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/slrn

only saying that it can be done.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; your use of `lsb_release` did not include the `-a` that shows all fields; and thus only related to LINUX STANDARD BASE modules which are not installed by default.

Comment: pardon, it's the most recent.  I'll update the question and try the below answer.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders Looks like you already have a nano setting available to you in your .slrnrc file. This character: % is used as a 'comment' character in this file and must be removed to enable the option. And good to see a fellow slrn user :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the source code, it looks like the editor is chosen as

1. an (uncommented) assignment of the form `set editor_command "..."` in the user's `.slrnrc` file
2. any of the following environment variables, in order:

   ```
    SLRN_EDITOR
    SLANG_EDITOR
    EDITOR
    VISUAL
   ```
3. an OS-specific default, which in the case of a Unix type OS is `vi`

So if you are observing that it is choosing `nano` rather than `vi` in the absence of an explicit `~/.slrnrc` assignment, it is likely due to one of the mentioned environment variables.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that